# How to upgrade Mozilla firefox in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, ubuntu

I am trying to update Firefox to latest version through the terminal using the sudo apt-get update command

Error message:

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Try http://askubuntu.com/ for ubuntu help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have some problems with DNS-service... Maybe you change some things on your router? Googling your problem will help, I think, because to help you there are some more details to know